# How to append user input from front end (i.e. HTML form) to the url

Tags: python, html, api, rest, flask

I have a basic HTML form which includes a text box and a submit button.
Let us say, the user types an input to the input box. I want to append that input to the existing URL of the home page.

Example: The URL of the home page be "localhost/home" and the user inputs "data" into the text box.

On the click of submit button, the URL should append the input and look something like: "localhost/home/data" (upon displaying the result fetched from backend using flask).

So, technically when I click submit, I want to be redirected to "localhost/home/data".

I'm using the below HTML form.

```
    <form action="/home" method="POST">
        <input type=text name="name">
        <input type=submit name="submit">
    </form>
```

and using this as the flask code snippet:

```
    @app.route('/home', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
    def basic():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            path = (my path to json file)
            with open(path) as f:
                data = json.load(f)
            format_list=data[name]
            return format_list

        return render_template('temp.html')
```

How can I get the inputted parameters from the form appended to the URL?
Thanks!

Comment: If you want it to be added *before* the form is submitted, you need to do this via JavaScript (because the logic won't hit the Python layer yet). If you want to do it *after* the form was submitted, it needs to be done in Python. Without further clarification of the questions it is hard to answer because there are just too many options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use form submission with flask, the form is exposed on the flask object as a `flask.request.form` python dictionary.  From here, you can access what was POSTed to your endpoint:

```
@app.route('/home', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def basic():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        path = request.form['name']
```

Do note you should be giving your input fields `id` attributes:

```
<input id="name" name="name">
```

If you want to append this to a path or something of that nature, then you can further look into `flask.redirect`.